# sitecore how to clear cache after content edit?

Tags: caching, sitecore

I'm editing field value in content manager, then i click save. After refresh page i see old value of field.  I tried increase version and clear cache manually:

```
        var context = new SitecoreContext();
        Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches();
        Item dda = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Serwisy/test");
```

daa item has old value. If i open page in incognito page i see correct value. How can i resolve it? The best resolve this problem will be clearing after click save but how can i do it?

Comment: Are you editing the item programatically or from the interface? Unless you are doing this programatically AND using a disabler, there should normally be no need to manually clear caches.

Answer (score 1):

> Remove Sitecore caching after login.

http://[hostname]/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx and click on clear all button.

[image]